# Nesting inner to sum inner query's result

Tags: join

Suppose I have a query `select a,b from xyz`

The result would be:

**a          b**
m1     10
m2     20
m3     30

Can I somehow sum all b's something like:

```
select sum(b) from (select a,b from xyz)
```

And it will give me result 60. Possible? Stupid question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to alias your inner query and **use SUM instead of COUNT.**

```
select SUM(b) from (select a,b from xyz) temp_table;
```

Instead of that you can do like

```
SELECT SUM(b) FROM xyz;
```

**Example**

```
SELECT userid,score FROM user_score;
+--------+-------+
| userid | score |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |     4 |
|      1 |     5 |
|      1 |     6 |
|      1 |     7 |
|      1 |     8 |
|      1 |     9 |
|      1 |    10 |
|      1 |     2 |
|      1 |     2 |
|      2 |     2 |
|      2 |     3 |
|      2 |     4 |
|      2 |     5 |
|      2 |     6 |
|      2 |     7 |
|      2 |     8 |
+--------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT SUM(score) FROM (SELECT userid,score FROM user_score ) A;
+------------+
| SUM(score) |
+------------+
|         88 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**OR**

```
SELECT SUM(score) FROM user_score;
+------------+
| SUM(score) |
+------------+
|         88 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Does this `(select a,b from xyz) temp_table;` means `(select a,b from xyz) as temp_table`?

Comment: Gotcha thanks Mr. Abdul Manaf and ypercuber

Comment: This answer is extremely high quality due to the super clear illustrations of execution.